How to add spaces between sentences but ignore links?
I need to put a space between sentences like:
"This is one.This is two"


should be:
"This is one. This is two"

In Python, I used the following regular expression:
text = re.sub(r'\.([A-Z])', r'. \1', text)

It worked pretty well until I have links in the text with dots inside, like:
"This is a text with link https://www.website.com/Article.Name.pdf" 

turned out to be:
"This is a text with link https://www.website.com/Article. Name.pd"

The case is important, it can't be changed. That is I need the regex to recognize it's a link and ignore it. Not sure how it can be done.

Check that the words around the . are surrounded by whitespace.

@Barmar not sure how.

\s matches whitespace. So put \s before the pattern for the first word, and \s after the pattern for the second word.

@Barmar can you please create the answer with an example - I don't understand what you mean.

You need to write an algorithm for this. Use r'(\b(?:https?:\/\/[^\s]+)\b|\b\w+\b)|([\w\W]+?)' and write an algorithm.

Two more ideas (demo) for skipping.

@bobblebubble Read the comments on the answer below. The op now wants text one.Text two has link www.Aaa.com.This is another to have www.Aaa.com recognised as a "link", and for there to be a space added before This.

You can't resolve this problem just with regex. For example, how do you split here is a link my.co.it is my personal website? both my.co and my.co.it are valid domain names.

Your question is incomplete as you have expressed it in terms of two examples, one where a space is to be inserted and the other where no space is to be inserted. Rarely are questions stated solely in terms of examples unambiguous, and this one is no exception. That is clearly demonstrated by the many "How about this string?" comments on the question and answers. You need to specify an unambiguous rule for determining where spaces are to be inserted. I have downvoted the question for it being vague.

You can try using re.sub with custom function where you decide whether to insert space or not, e.g.:
import re

testcases = [
    "This is one.This is two",
    "This is a text with link https://www.website.com/Article.Name.pdf",
    "text one.Text two has link www.Aaa.com.This is another",
]


def decide_what_to_do(g):
    first_group = g.group(1)
    if "http" in first_group:
        return g.group(0)
    return f"{g.group(1)}. {g.group(2)}"


for t in testcases:
    out = re.sub(r"(\S*)\.([A-Z])", decide_what_to_do, t)

    print(t)
    print(out)
    print()

Prints:
This is one.This is two
This is one. This is two

This is a text with link https://www.website.com/Article.Name.pdf
This is a text with link https://www.website.com/Article.Name.pdf

text one.Text two has link www.Aaa.com.This is another
text one. Text two has link www.Aaa.com. This is another


Perfect! I want to find out if there are sentences that wouldn't pass this test :))) hopefully, not!

Can you please explain how it "decides" correctly about "www" link without "http" part? I guess it's because of the right regular expression?

@mimic try 'text one.Text two has link www.Aaa.com. This is another'. (note the space between com. and This) and see how it breaks this code

Or foo www.bar.com/readme.EN.pdf baz however it's doing pretty well what was asked for and can be further adjusted. There won't be a bulletproof solution to this problem?

Only match words that are surrounded by whitespace.
text = re.sub(r'(\s\w+)\.(\w+\s)', r'\1 . \2', text)

This assumes you don't have any 1-word sentences that are connected like this.
You can improve it by matching the beginning/end of the input along with the whitespace.
text = re.sub(r'((?:^|\s)\w+)\.(\w+(?:\s|$))', r'\1 . \2', text)

This won't work for 3 one-word sentences in a row, though.

Unfortunately, I need a more universal solution. Your solution doesn't work for this example "text one.Text two has link www.Aaa.com.This is another"

How can that possibly be fixed? www.aaa.com.this is a potential hostname (if IANA adds a .this TLD).

You said "ignore links". A hostname by itself is not a link.

Anyway, if you want something much better than this, you'll probably need to use NLP, you're getting outside the capabilities of regular expressions.

www.aaa.com.this is a link

www.aaa.com.this is a hostname. https://www.aaa.com.this is a URL.

It's just not a well formed link, but it's a 100% link. You can see such links everywhere in texts, emails etc. and they are still links.

And it can sometimes be annoying when the application turns hostnames into links. Slack does this, and it's a PITA when we're discussing servers and naming them.
